# Android Service onStartCommand() fired when the app force closes

Tags: android, service, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I start a `Service`from within an `Activity` and then I bind the Activity to it.
If I try to force close the app from the Task Manager, the Service `onStartCommand()` method is called and a NullPointerException is called. I don't understand why onStartCommand() is called.

The Service has just onStartCommand() overriden for now:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  //This is line 24
    //some stuff to get strings from bundle
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The exception:

```
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.app.GameService@420edf78 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2782)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:152)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at com.app.GameService.onStartCommand(GameService.java:24)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2765)
07-16 14:49:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(24607):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Do you have any code in onDestroy() of your activity/service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sth like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("Log", "Bundle is null");

    }
}
```

Comment: `getIntent()` is not defined for Services. I solved checking if `intent != null`but i don't understand why onStartCommand() is called.

Answer (score 0):

May be returning Service.Start_not_sticky from onStartCommand() is what you want. I don't know your scenario, just give it a shot.

This will help better understand diffeent mode of finishing/restarting the service - 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY